# Embedded linux filename length

Tags: embedded, filenames, udev

I am using an arm development platform. There I installed udev and it works perfect. But when I mount a pen drive and see the file content all files and folders with names having more than 8 chars have been replaced with "~" char. 
eg: myfilename.mp3 is replaced with myfile~e.mp3

Before udev installation it worked well. (All file names appeared normally).
What should I do?

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to filename length limitation in Linux. This happened because this drive was mounted as FAT16. Check if FAT32 is supported and try mount it this way (check udev rules in **/etc/udev/rules.d/**).

Comment: Hi, In etc/udev/rules.d/ I wrote a rule. The purpose of this rule is to assign node "pen1" for this "1-1" port whenever a pen is mounted.  this is how I wrote my rule.                               BUS=="usb", ID=="1-1", KERNEL=="sd?1", NAME="pen1"

Comment: Please, update your question with this info and log related to mounting: tail -f /var/log/messages just before plugging in.

Comment: Also take a look at the http://gnuru.org/article/1561/usb-pen-drives-udev-automounting-secrets, note config MOUNTOPTIONS and FS_MOUNTOPTIONS

Comment: Hi pmod, It was a problem with mount command.After adding -vfat argument in to my mount command problem solved.so thank you very much for your advices.

Comment: I'm glad if something was helpful, by the way I was thinking that your issue with hotplug therefore suggesting to look at udev rules.