# udev pen drive filename length

Tags: embedded, usb, filenames, udev

I have a problem with mounting pen drive using udev. I am working in an arm development platform and installed udev successfully. My udev rules are as follow.
BUS=="usb", ID=="1-1", KERNEL=="sd?1", NAME="pen1"
What I want here is to assign node "pen1" whenever a pen is mounted to port "1-1". udev works fine but when I mount using "mount /dev/pen1 /mnt" and access the content, the filenames appear corrupted and show only 8 bits.
eg: myfilename.mp3 is replaced with myfile~e.mp3

what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672948/embedded-linux-filename-length

Comment: I should add that you shouldn't post multiple questions that are the same here as it is likely that all the duplictaes will get closed and you will only have one question open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, make sure you are mounting with filesystem type vfat -- and make sure your kernel is compiled to offer VFAT support (it's a sub-option of fat).